# Why is my trigger passing in null values into my insert statements?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

So there is a Stored Procedure that inserts data into a table called xml_hours_load_2. The Insert is fine and data is being inserted, however; when my trigger is fired, it seems to be loading nulls into all 'NEW' referenced columns. I know this because when i turn my trigger on and try to load data into xml_hours_load_2, i receive a cannot insert NULL into (VALUE."VALUE_TX")' error. What am I doing wrong? I've tried just hardcoding in a value for VALUE_Tx, then i get the same error for HR. My code is below and  thanks in advance!

my xml_hours_load_2 table has the following columns:

```
row_id
utc_offset
processed
data_date
hr_utc
value_Tx
hr
hr_num
data_code
data_type

create or replace TRIGGER xml_load_trigger_value
AFTER INSERT
ON xml_hours_load_2
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (
NEW.processed = 'N'
  ) DECLARE 
Value_ID Number;
pValue_ID Number;
Hr_Utc Varchar2(4);
p_Entity_Address_ID Varchar2(50);
New_Value_ID Number;
New_Value_Tx varchar2(50);
NEW_UTC_Offset varchar2(50);

BEGIN

Value_ID := value_value_id_seq.NEXTVAL;
New_Value_ID := Value_id;
Calculation_Value_ID :=CALCULATION_VALUE_CALCULATI329.NEXTVAL;
calculation_id := Calculation_Calculation_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL;


Insert into Value
(VALUE_ID, PRODUCT_ID, DATA_SOURCE_ID, UNIT_CD, VALUE_TX, UTC_OFFSET, DATA_DATE, HR_UTC, HR, HR_NUM, DATA_CODE, CREATE_DT, CREATE_USER_ID)
VALUES
   (Value_ID, '109' , '269', 'NA', :NEW.Value_Tx, :NEW.UTC_Offset, :NEW.Data_Date, :NEW.hr_utc, :NEW.hr, :NEW.hr_num, :NEW.data_code, SYSDATE, '15');
```

Comment: Is the sequence working well?

Comment: yeah all 3 sequences are working well...

Comment: So the obvious goes to the VALUE_TX field, apparently is null during the insert in xml_hours_load_2

Comment: yeah but why? everything is defined correctly and there are new values being inserted for those fields...

Comment: DBMS_OUTPUT or debugg, see what exactly is getting as new values your trigger

Comment: probably a dumb question but how would i get it to display? i put in DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(:NEW.VALUE_TX) right after the begin and nothing at all is showing for me. just the errors

Comment: set serveroutput on

Comment: @icerabbit what is the value that you find on xml_hours_load_2.VALUE_TX?

Comment: You haven't shown the insert statement in the procedure, into `xml_hours_load_2`; it seems to be *that* which is inserting nulls, the trigger is just passing them on to `value`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just reference the sequences directly in your INSERT statement:

```
insert into t (x) values(myseq.nextval);
```